# CSS3 Columns span vertically

Tags: php, html, css

I'm making a basic columns layout for photos with CSS3 `Columns`,

the problem is that in this way, it will first align content vertically and and then go to next column

for example consider this: http://jsfiddle.net/LQEfK/1/

here as you can see first second and third `img` are in first `column`.
I found `-webkit-column-axis` which is not much documented and is suported only by Chrome.

```
<div class="image-gallery main">
    <?php while ( bp_has_images() ) : bp_the_image(); ?>
        <div class="image-thumb-box">
            <img alt="<?php bp_gallplus_image_id() ?>" src="<?php bp_image_mid_url() ?>" alt="">
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Now I want to remake this php to align with this CSS.
Like save make 3 variables in `while` loop and each should contain a column which will be right for css  `columns`

Comment: If you *don't* arrange them with columns, they'll align in rows, from left-to-right (by default, which can be changed to right-to-left if desired).

Comment: what browser? you specifically target -webkit based.

Comment: ou sorry I just copied webkit, I will update it now, but thats not problem
@DavidThomas what do you mean?

Comment: You want the images to fill rows first, rather than columns? So why are you arranging them with columns, why not just use rows (the default for inline elements)?

Comment: because I want this style images, like [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) you know, same width but different height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've done;

```
<div class="image-gallery main">
    <?php
        $key = 1;
        $column_one = '';
        $column_two = '';
        $column_three = '';
    ?>
    <?php while ( bp_gallplus_has_images() ) : bp_gallplus_the_image(); ?>
        <?php

            if($key == 1) {
                $column_one .= '<img data-postid="'. bp_gallplus_get_image_id() .'" data-org="'. bp_gallplus_get_image_url() .'" class="media-popover" data-pop="popover" src="'. bp_gallplus_get_image_mid_url() .'" alt="">';
                $key++;
            } else if ($key == 2) {
                $column_two .= '<img data-postid="'. bp_gallplus_get_image_id() .'" data-org="'. bp_gallplus_get_image_url() .'" class="media-popover" data-pop="popover" src="'. bp_gallplus_get_image_mid_url() .'" alt="">';
                $key++;

            } else {
                $column_three .= '<img data-postid="'. bp_gallplus_get_image_id() .'" data-org="'. bp_gallplus_get_image_url() .'" class="media-popover" data-pop="popover" src="'. bp_gallplus_get_image_mid_url() .'" alt="">';
                $key = 1;
            }
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php echo $column_one . $column_two . $column_three; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code just targets -webkit based browsers...

try this instead

```
.image-gallery {
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap:   3px;  
  -moz-column-count:    3;
  -moz-column-gap:      3px;
  column-count:         3;
  column-gap:           3px;
}
```